# Execute Mono in parallel

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have following classes

```
class A {
  private Long id;
  private Long rid; //Joins A with B1 and B2.
  //Other data.
}

class B1 {
  private Long rid; //Joins with A
  private Long cid; //Joins with C
  //other data.
}

class B2 {
  private Long rid;  //Joins with A
  private Long cid;  //Joins with C
  //other data.
}

class C {
  private Long id;
  //other data.
}
```

`A` comes from `a` table in database. `B1`, `B2` and `C` from `b1`, `b2` and `c` tables respectively.

Now my logic is like following:

1. Get latest 1000 rows of A.
2. From A, get B1 and B2 on element rid.
3. From B1 and B2, get C.
4. Now, compare A and C on some parameter and produce the report.

In webflux, my code is like as follows (code is in Java 17):

```
 class StageResult {
   private List<A> aList;
   private List<Long> rids;
   private List<Long> cids1;
   private List<Long> cids2;
   private List<C> c;
 }

 var stageResult = new StageResult();
 var page = PageRequest.of(0, 1000);
 getA(page).collectList()
 .flatMap(aList -> {
     stageResult.setAList(aList);
     stageResult.setRids(aList.stream().map(A::getRid).collect(Collectors.toList()))
     return Mono.just(stageResult);
 }).
 .flatMapMany(x -> getB1(x.getRids())) //Stage 2
    .map(B1::getCid).collectList()
    .flatMap(cids -> {
      stageResult.setCids1(cids);
      return Mono.just(stageResult);
    })
 .flatMapMany(x -> getB2(x.getRids())) //Stage 3
    .map(B2::getCid).collectList()
    .flatMap(cids -> {
      stageResult.setCids2(cids);
      return Mono.just(stageResult);
  })
 .flatMapMany(x -> {
   var list = new ArrayList<Long>(x.getCids1());
   list.addAll(x.getCids2());
   return getC(list)
        .collectList().map(y -> {
           x.setC(y);
           return x;
         });
 }).flatMap(x -> {
   //Compare the element
 });
```

In this case, stage 2 and 3 can be executed in parallel. Just want to know that how we can execute 2 and 3 in parallel. One approach is to create separate stage 2 and stage 3 by stage 1. Cache the result of stage 1. And then zip stage 2 and stage 3 before stage 4 and use the result.

Comment: Well don't. Just write 1 query that retrieves everything in one go instead of doing 1+N select issues or even (1 + 2*N). This solution is slow and even in parallel it will be slow.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum. However, we still need to consider when the result is coming from APIs, not from database. I am considering your option for db based data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Flux.merge` to resolve publishers in parallel.

> Merge data from Publisher sequences contained in an array / vararg into an interleaved merged sequence. Unlike `concat`, sources are subscribed to eagerly.

```
.flatMapMany(x -> Flux.merge(
        getB1(x.getRids()).map(B1::getCid), //Stage 2
        getB2(x.getRids()).map(B2::getCid)  //Stage 3
    )
)
.collectList()
```

**btw**

It doesn't make sense to create "pseudo-async" publishers using `Mono.just` and then resolve using `flatMap`.

```
.flatMap(cids -> {
      stageResult.setCids1(cids);
      return Mono.just(stageResult);
})
```

Use can use simple `map` instead.

```
.map(cids -> {
      stageResult.setCids1(cids);
      return stageResult;
})
```